# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace',

Tags: python

```
testdeck = ['apple', 'banana', 'napalm', 'ice','rock','death','plush','rush']
finaldeck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for card in testdeck:
    index = testdeck.index(card)
    print('index',index,'card',card)
    
    for item in finaldeck:
        if type(item) == int:
            print(item,'integer','replacing...')
            finaldeck = finaldeck.replace(item,card)
        elif type(item) == str:
            print(item,'string'' not replacing...')


#example(end game)

exampledeck = ['banana','apple]
exmapledeck2 = [1,2,3,4]


exampledeck2 = ['banana','apple,3,4]
```

Finaldeck already has 8 items, each one being an integer
the idea is that every string in testdeck will need to be placed in the first integer found available in finaldeck.

Comment: But every item is already an `int`. Did you mean: `finaldeck = testdeck[:]`?

Comment: Please update your question with finaldeck including at least one string. Plus a note about what the numbers mean.

Comment: Indeed, lists do not have a `.replace()` method.  If you want to replace an item, just assign it: `mylist[index] = newitem`

Comment: I see you have edited the question to include a description of what needs to happen. I am still confused. Please give an actual example of the final output.

Comment: example included

Comment: Yes, that looks similar if not the same to what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use zip and enumerate together:

```py
testdeck = ['apple', 'banana', 'napalm', 'ice','rock','death','plush','rush']
finaldeck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for index, (card, item) in enumerate(zip(testdeck, finaldeck)):
    if isinstance(item, int):
        finaldeck[index] = card
```

This is a single pass through both lists at the same time, terminating at the end of the shortest list.

Comment: It works mate, idk how but it does lol.  Now I'll attempt to understand the code and add it to the mother boat

Comment: Just search for “python zip and enumerate together”. That’s what I did.

Comment: I have a question  quamrana, what would I do to call upon a function once it's done scanning, only calling after everything is scanned and added

Comment: Just call the function. Any function f which you want to call can be called like: f().  If you mean that you want to pass your updated list as a parameter it would be: f(finaldeck)